# Springboot MongoDB delete an object from array of objects

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to delete an object from an array of objects in `mongodb` collection. I've followed multiple answers from SO but I couldn't able to make it work.

`customer_id` and `address_pin` will be passed from querystring. I want to remove an object from `address_india` where `address_pin` matches with the value passed via querystring.

`MongoDB collection object`

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"61fa7de3b3de485b30403c56"
   },
   "customer_id":"c7e690cf-c8d9-4a7b-b146-ade742958452",
   "customer_addresses":{
      "address_india":[
         {
            "address_id":"ccc428bd-3e4d-49e5-8569-ebacb181ad1e",
            "address_pin":"MD0BuCQUxT",  // I've to remove this object          
            "address_type":"sales"
         },
         {
            "address_id":"ccc428bd-3e4d-49e5-8569-ebacb181asdf",
            "address_pin":"MD0BuCQUXy",            
            "address_type":"marketing"
         }
      ]
   },
   "create_timestamp":{
      "$numberLong":"1643806179346"
   },
   "modified_timestamp":{
      "$numberLong":"1643806179346"
   }
}
```

`Controller`

```
return new ResponseEntity<CustomerAddressResponse>(
                this.customerAddressService.deleteCustomerAddressById(customerId),
                HandleResponseHeader.getResponseHeaders(UUID), HttpStatus.OK);
```

`ServiceImpl`

```
@Override
    public CustomerAddressResponse deleteCustomerAddressById(String customerId)
            throws Exception {

        try {
            if (isValidUUID(customerId)) {
                Date now = new Date();
                Long dateStartTime = now.getTime();
                Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
                CustomerAddress customerAddress = customerAddressDao
                        .findByCustomerId(customerId);
                String pin = httpServletRequest.getParameter("address_pin")
                        .trim();
                
                Query query = new Query();
                query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("customer_id")
                        .is(customerId)
                        .and("customer_addresses.address_india")
                        .elemMatch(Criteria.where("address_pin").is(pin)));
                
                Update update = new Update();
                update.pull("customer_addresses.address_india", new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("address_pin").is(pin)));
                FindAndModifyOptions options = FindAndModifyOptions.options();
                options.returnNew(true);
                MongoTemplate template = null;
                template.findAndModify(query, update, options, CustomerAddress.class);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `template.findAndModify(query, update, options, CustomerAddress.class);`

**How do I delete an object from array of objects in `mongodb` from `springboot`?**

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do from mongo js shell for single document , it may give you some idea on how to do from springboot:

```
db.collection.update(
 {
  "customer_id": "c7e690cf-c8d9-4a7b-b146-ade742958452"},
 {
   $pull: {
   "customer_addresses.address_india": {
   "address_pin": "MD0BuCQUxT"
   }
 }
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cdfIWM4Q8r5)