# Springboot mongodb - how to verify object has been removed from array of objects?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Based on my previous question [Springboot MongoDB delete an object from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70962312/springboot-mongodb-delete-an-object-from-array-of-objects) I'm able to remove an object from an array of objects in `mongodb` collection. Below code is working for me to remove:

```
String pin = httpServletRequest.getParameter("address_pin")
                        .trim();                           
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("customer_id")
                .is(customerId)
                .and("customer_addresses.address_india")
                .elemMatch(Criteria.where("address_pin").is(pin)));
                            
Update update = new Update();
update.pull("customer_addresses.address_india", Collections.singletonMap("address_pin", pin));
                            
UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, "customer_addresses");
System.out.println("::: DELETE SUCCESS ::: " + result.wasAcknowledged());
                            
    //  FindAndModifyOptions options = FindAndModifyOptions.options();
    //  options.returnNew(true);
    //  CustomerAddress addressesAfterDelete =  mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, options, CustomerAddress.class);
    //  System.out.println("::: AFTER DELETE ::: " + addressesAfterDelete.getCustomerAddresses().toString());
```

Here, `updateMulti` and `findAndModify` both are working fine. I can verify in Compass that the object matching with the criteria has been removed.

Is there any built-in method in `UpdateResult` or in `FindAndModifyOptions` to verify?
`result.wasAcknowledged()` returns `true` even if query criteria does not meet.

**How do I verify delete in `mongodb` was successful or not in `spring-boot`?**

Comment: If it was not successful there would've been an error/exception thrown.

Comment: [findAndModify - return data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#return-data) can show the updated document.